# Inserting a blank page using pdfpages results in "Missing number, treated as zero"

Tags: external-files, pdfpages

I am using the `pdfpages` package (version 25688 0.4r) to create a document with a blank page followed by a PDF file. Here is the working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={{},-}]{../ma532/hw11/hw11.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The empty braces in the pages argument required for the blank page throw up a "Missing number, treated as zero" error. However on pressing return in the command prompt after the error, compilation (with pdflatex) takes place as usual and gives me the required PDF. 
If I remove the blank page, the document is compiled smoothly.

As the same code works without any errors for version 0.4p of the package, I am wondering if the syntax for blank pages has changed in the new version. The documentation does not report any changes though. I had updated my TexLive distribution only a few days prior to running into this problem.

In short my question is this, am I using the wrong syntax or is there some other reason for the error.

Comment: I am not receiving any error using a quick test (TeX Live 2009 with `pdfpages` 2010/01/12 v0.4j). If you need a blank starting page, you could just issue a `\mbox{}\newpage` before using `\includepdf[pages=-]{...}`.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It seems that the error only occurs in the latest version of the package updated in CTAN repos only a couple of weeks back. I have reverted to the backup version of the package from TexLive and everything works as normal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The creator of the package sent me this patch – save as `pdfpages.fix`:

```
\ProvidesFile{pdfpages.fix}[2012/04/03 v0.4r Patch for pdfpages.sty (AM)]
\def\AM@patch{v0.4r}

\ifx\AM@fileversion\AM@patch\else
  \PackageWarningNoLine{pdfpages}{^^J%
  *** Patch file `pdfpages.fix' version \AM@patch^^J%
  *** does not match to `pdfpages.sty' version \AM@fileversion.^^J%
  *** Patch file not loaded}%
  \expandafter\endinput
\fi


\newif\ifAM@integer
\begingroup
\@makeother_
\gdef\AM@checkinteger#1{%
  \ifcat _\ifnum9<1#1_\else A\fi
    \AM@integertrue
  \else
    \AM@integerfalse
  \fi
}
\endgroup

%%% Local Variables: ***
%%% mode:latex ***
%%% End: ***
```

Put the file to a place where TeX can find it, e.g. the current directory. This should fix it.